# How can I easily convert logstash filters with grok to ingest pipelines?

Tags: elasticsearch

Logstash has ingest-convert.sh to convert ingest pipelines to Logstash, but I'd like to convert the other way around.

I have the 23-Tomcat-filters and grok_patterns file.

Is there any smart way that would save me time writing all json files to this ingest pipeline-format, based on the current logstash configuration?

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/ujjain
{
  "description" : "Pipeline ujjain",
  "processors": [
    {
      "grok": {
        "field": "message",
        "patterns": ["%{MONTH}%{SPACE}%{MONTHDAY},%{SPACE}%{YEAR}%{SPACE}%{HOUR}:?%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND})%{SPACE}(?:AM|PM)%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:class}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:type_log}%{SPACE}%{WORD:loglevel}:%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:log_text}"]
    }
```

...

Comment: Any solution found? I am looking for such solution.